# PatchForm not working after api call Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

i am using patch value to update my form but i am unable to do that, my view is not getting updated , though i have tried both approaches async/await and observable. Although i found a workaround by using set timeout but that is not a proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Approach 1 using arrow function and async/await (promise)

```
constructor(
    public storage: Storage,
    public route: Router,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    public alertController: AlertController,
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public dataInteractionService: DataInteractionService,
    public router: ActivatedRoute
) {
    super(storage, route, navCtrl, toastController, alertController, loadingController);
    this.initialize_Sub_for_Param();
}
    
initialize_Sub_for_Param() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        debugger;
        this.initialize_Form();
        if (this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            debugger;
            this.petDetails = this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.user;
            console.log(this.petDetails, "petDetails")
            this.get_Data_animal(this.petDetails);

        }    
    });
}    

ngOnInit() {}

initialize_Form() {
    this.edit_animal_Form = this.formBuilder.group({
        animal_image: ['', Validators.required],
        animal_name: ['', Validators.required],
        species_id: ['', Validators.required],
        breed_id: ['', Validators.required],
        date_of_birth: ['', Validators.required],
        electronic_number: ['', Validators.required],
    })
}
get_Data_animal = async (form_Value) => {
    try {
        let breed_Species_data = await this.dataInteractionService.get_Animal_Spcices().toPromise();
        this.get_species = breed_Species_data['species'];
        this.get_breeds = breed_Species_data['breeds'];
        debugger;

        //Workaround using settimeout but I know this is not a proper solution//

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.edit_animal_Form.patchValue(form_Value);
            console.log(this.edit_animal_Form.value);
        }, 100);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Approach 2 using observables

```
constructor(
    public storage: Storage,
    public route: Router,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    public alertController: AlertController,
    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public dataInteractionService: DataInteractionService,
    public router: ActivatedRoute
) {
    super(storage, route, navCtrl, toastController, alertController, loadingController);
    this.initialize_Sub_for_Param();
}
    
initialize_Sub_for_Param() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.initialize_Form();
        if (this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            this.petDetails = this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.user;
            this.get_Data_animal(this.petDetails);

        }    
    });
}    

ngOnInit() {}

initialize_Form() {
    this.edit_animal_Form = this.formBuilder.group({
        animal_image: ['', Validators.required],
        animal_name: ['', Validators.required],
        species_id: ['', Validators.required],
        breed_id: ['', Validators.required],
        date_of_birth: ['', Validators.required],
        electronic_number: ['', Validators.required],
    })
}

get_Data_animal = async (form_Value) => {
    try {
        this.dataInteractionService.get_Animal_Spcices().subscribe(res => {
            this.get_species = breed_Species_data['species'];
            this.get_breeds = breed_Species_data['breeds'];
            this.edit_animal_Form.patchValue(form_Value);

        });    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is going on in your code. But here is a fair example which i use to patch values in my form. I can give you the basic concept. Patch your form right after when you receive the values. For example:

```
  getOrderById(id) {
    this._order.getOrderWithId(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.orderForm.patchValue(res);
    });
  }
```

In this case you dont have to use setTimeout or any other async await stuff.

Comment: i already use the same thing in my second approach but it did not work

Comment: Try to use this line `this.edit_animal_Form.patchValue(this.petDetails)` in this function  `initialize_Sub_for_Param`